# I need to programmatically identify all libraries and data files read by several hundred SAS program files. Can this be accomplished programmatically?

Tags: sas

Scenario: We have a list of over 200 SAS files. We need to identify all SAS libraries and data sets used as inputs to these programs, and write out a table linking the SAS input data sets to the associated program files. We are not SAS programmers and are just now becoming familiar with the language.  The intent is to design a rearchitecture of the logic of the SAS files to be more modular.
We are conducting this analysis statically - i.e., we are not running SAS, we are attempting to extract this data purely from interrogating the code in program files themselves and we do not have access to the data files.

Solution attempted: we have parsed the SAS programs to identify inputs to SAS Procs and SAS Data steps, however there are several challenges. The approach we are using is as follows:

1. We have obtained a python-based parser (https://github.com/benjamincorcoran/sasdocs) that extracts key information from SAS files.  We have applied it to all 200+ files and extracted parsed content into a text file. However, not all SAS syntax is supported; in particular, DataSet blocks are left as unparsed raw text, Procs with a variable number and names of arguments may be missed, and some commands, like various constructs of “set” and “merge” are missed completely by the grammar that has been implemented in the parser so far.
2. The parser correctly locates about 60% of the files, especially the libraries and files preceded by a "Set" statement. For reasons we do not understand, not all libraries/files preceded by a "SET" command are captured by this parser.
3. In addition to the "Set" command, we have observed that SAS can also reference a library/file within a Merge or Sort procedure, without a specific Set command.
4. We are ignoring SAS files from within the 'work' library that are created during processing; we are only concerned with external input files.
5. Note that we are not running these programs, we only have access to the SAS Program file sources - hence we do not have access to a SAS log.

Questions:

1. Is there a more direct way do accomplish this goal?  Does SAS understand what files it reads and writes, and is there a method of extracting a list of all libraries and files read by SAS associated with a SAS program?
2. If there is no method of accomplishing this information programmatically, what are all the ways that SAS can access or reference an external library/file, other than within a SET, MERGE or SORT procedure?

Comment: Shoot. I used to have a macro that did *exactly* this by parsing the log! If I find it I'll post it here.

Comment: I do a lot of this in my utility that is in .NET. I will be presenting it in October at SESUG. What you are probably running into is the parsing of the SET statements. Focus on the FILENAMES and LIBNAMES. They are what provide the most information. You are also running into an issue with the metalanguages that are in SAS. Specifically, MACRO language, and dataset modifiers. You have to fine tune your regex to capture everything. Also, there is no public lexer/parser for SAS. SAS does not lend itself to things like ANTLR.

Comment: One other comment, The LIBNAMES tell you the dirs which contain the datasets. FILENAMEs are merely the raw data files. A dataset has an extension of sas7bdat. If the LIBNAME points to a DB table, you have to discover the tables in the DB. If the LIBNAME points to a hierarchical source, such as XML or JSON, the SET will point to the library and then the leaf in the node.

Comment: This also assumes no macros which would be unlikely in 200 files where the code is dynamically generated. The input datasets would not be in SET/MERGE statements ever in those cases.

Comment: Thanks StuSztukowski , AlanC, Reeza,whymath, and especially @joe for the useful PROC!

Answer (score 3):

SAS has a procedure that does this, [PROC SCAPROC](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p0k5uaxpaz2uzin1qvbqmmafnqtl.htm).  If you do have access to SAS, this is by far the best solution.  You would technically need to run SAS, but even if there are errors, in theory it might work okay - the fact that the dataset doesn't exist should be okay, unless your code is data driven.

If you're unable to run the code or run anything in SAS, you'd need to do something with text analysis.

The key things to look for which would catch *most* of the possibilities would be (in sort of pseudo regex code):

- `data [lib.]dataset(could have parens but ignore them);`
- `set( [lib.]dataset(ignore parens))*` (could have multiple)
- `merge( [lib.]dataset(ignore parens))*` (could have multiple)
- `update( [lib.]dataset(ignore parens))*` (could have multiple)
- `modify( [lib.]dataset(ignore parens))*` (could have multiple)
- `data=[lib.]dataset(ignore parens)` - this is for most PROCs input, could have spaces around the equals sign
- `out=[lib.]dataset(ignore parens)` - this is for most PROCs output, could have spaces around the equals sign

To get more than the "most" above, you'd want to analyze which PROCs were used.  Each PROC can have its own output/input options, for example `proc surveyselect` could use various different datasets for different things, `proc format` uses CNTLIN and CNTLOUT, etc.  You'd also have to see if there are hash tables or other objects used in the code as that has its own elements.

The other thing you could do, only caring about *external* files, is identify the `libname` statements.  Once you find them, it's possible you could just look for `libname.data` in the program - that's how all of the datasets in the external folders (libraries) will be referred to.  This won't work, though, if you are using metadata-assigned libraries, unless there are a small enough number of them that you could possibly list them all out (and you have access to SAS to find out the list).

Ultimately, your 100% solution is to hire a SAS consultant to look at the code; without being able to run the code (and thus use SCAPROC), there's not really a perfect solution.

Comment: What a cool proc! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Joe, thank you - a lot to digest here, but the SCAPROC command sounds like a great place to start.   Very much appreciated in addition to the other options above that list out some of the other procs.

Comment: Cooooool! By the way, If you are going to do text analysis on SAS code, don't forget `proc sql` and `proc iml`. These procedure have different grammar.